# Powering LED and DC motor with USBC PD

Tags: led, usb-c

I'm looking to power a circuit with USB-c with a trigger board negotiating 20Vin up to 2A.
The circuit would consists of a high power LED strip that runs 21.5V @1A and a DC motor water pump rated for 12V 300mA.

My thoughts are to have them connect in parallel.
I would use a step-up converter with constant current to regulate current through the LED
I would use a step-down converter with constant current to regulate current to the DC motor.

Is this a good approach or is that completely wrong?

Comment: OMG, you seems to be talking about 9 things at the same time. I lost count at 5 things :)  To be considerate to poor IQ97 guys like me, perhaps you can split your 9 things into 3 or 4 questions. For example, you can have your first question only on USB talking to 20V, 2A guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long you are within the limits, I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Negotiating on USB-C is not easy though, you will need some specialized chips and they are still sparse as USB-C is fairly new, not all stacks are implemented, that is the most tricky part of this project.

Be careful about the inductance of the motor, I don't think USB-C is designed to supply current to inductive load so you need to make sure that kickbacks aren't going to be a problem. If you have a step-down converter it should negate the problem though.

It makes more sense to have them in parallel as you will have fewer losses on the DC/DC converters and will need a smaller size.